# Behat from batch file with error handler

Tags: windows, batch-file, error-handling, behat

It's hard for me to explain my problem, so let's see the code :

```
@echo off
cls
set errors=0

bin\behat > test.txt || set /A errors=errors+1

if %errors% EQU 0 goto ok
goto ko

:ok
echo .
echo .OK
goto end

:ko
echo .
echo .KO


:end
```

When I launch this batch file, I never see the OK/KO output. It looks like the batch stopped after the call to behat. But I need it to continue, in order to detect errors and manage them.

This batch works fine with other calls and I need behat being called after them. Has someone an idea to resolve this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `bin\behat.bat`, a batch file.

When a batch file directly invokes another one, the execution flow is transfered to the called one and does not return to the caller.

To call another batch file and allow the execution to return to the caller, you will need to use the `call` command

```
....
call bin\behat > test.txt || set /A errors=errors+1
....
```